# Winforms: Multiline TextBox content disappears after a certain number of characters

Tags: powershell, winforms, textbox, multiline

I have a simple form with a textbox:

[image]

If I supply the textbox with four lines of:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."

The text simply refuses to render:

[image]

If I delete the fourth line, the text renders again:

[image]

What is causing this? I am completely stumped. The TextBox's `MaxLength` is 32767 characters.

Here's a video: https://streamable.com/zd8ck6

Anyone know what's going on? Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:powershell]?

Comment: I'm using PowerShell Pro Tools. They have a Winforms template so you can design forms and it generates appropriate PowerShell code.

Comment: So I tried the same thing with the C# Winforms template, and it behaves correctly. This is leading me to believe that the issue is somehow related to PowerShell Pro Tools. I'm not completely sure.